# How to remove a link and add a function instead

Tags: jquery

I have a closed system without the possibility to edit the html/css files.
It generates something like this:

```
<li>
   <a href="exp.html">Linktext</a>
</li>
```

I want to remove the `href` attribute and replace it with a `slideToggle` function.

So far I have tried to write something like this:

```
$('li').removeAttr('href');
$('li').click(function(){
    $('#example').slideToggle();
});
```

I need to keep the `<a>` tag for its styling. For those who like it [here is a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/yqeva05a/2/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing that comes to my mind is preventing your page from navigating to `exp.html`:

```
$('li').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#example').slideToggle();
});
```

Basically, by preventing the default action of the `click` on this `<a>` element, you can stop the page from navigating to `exp.html` and call `$("#example").slideToggle();` all in one go.

Comment: Yep.  preventDefault() is the way to go!

Comment: I'm currently on my phone, but does this prevent the default behaviour of clicking the contained link? Given that the handler is attached to a parent, by the time the event propagates wouldn't the default behaviour have already happened? I haven't, and can't easily, check but intuitively it feels like it shouldn't quite work.

Comment: @DavidThomas Hmm,  that's a good point, will make a quick edit

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I have made a fiddle for "quick checks", it really does not work for @DavidThomas reason http://jsfiddle.net/yqeva05a/

Comment: I saw it just at this moment! I am really sorry! I do not know why, but on my site it still does not work. I will have to figure out whats blocking this code, since my console doesn't log any errors.

Comment: Is it a live site we can help debug for you? Or can you create an exact replica in Fiddle? Theoretically this should work for you, even if it is a bit odd as @DavidThomas mentioned.